# Possible to download a folder of images as a zip file within Assets?

Tags: add-on, assets

I'm using Assets 1.2.2. Is it possible to enable a client to download the contents of a file upload directory as a single zip file within Assets? If not, I'd welcome any other suggestions (or maybe it's a feature coming in Assets 2?) other than using FTP or the EE File Manager.

I've just looked into using EE File Manager and it allows you to select files (upto a page at a time) and download them as a zip file. Besides only being able to download one page at a time, the other reason I want to avoid this is that I don't want clients editing/deleting images via the File Manager (which might happen if they are given access to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not a feature of the Assets addon.

You could create your own functionality in a password protected EE template using [**this tutorial**](http://www.chaosm.net/blog/2010/05/22/php-zip-a-directory-of-images/) and a selectable list of the Assets directories.

Comment: Shame there's no better EE solution, but thanks for the alternative suggestion.

Comment: I'd suggest sending P&T a feature request on this.

Comment: Good idea, thanks - I'll tweet them now. Kind of hoped they'd see it here anyway as they're now using EESE for support too.

Comment: They may have seen it but EESE isn't for feature requests so best to contact them directly.